# How to properly fetch a NSFetchrequest xcode 8 auto generated code data with swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift3, xcode8

I am working on a swift 3 tutorial and have a problem with core data.
When running the code i am able to save my data, i think, but when i want to load it into my control i get an error.
[image of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnX4Q.png)

This is my code:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
   let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    return context
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func speichernPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    writeData()
}

@IBAction func ladenPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    loadData()
}

func writeData() {
    let kontakt = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Kontakte", into: self.managedObjectContext!) as! Kontakte
    kontakt.vorname = vornameTextField.text!
    kontakt.name = nameTextField.text!
    kontakt.plz = plzTextField.text
    kontakt.ort = ortTextField.text!
    kontakt.strasse = straßeTextField.text!

    do{
        try managedObjectContext?.save()
    } catch {
    }
    showAlertViewWithTitle(title: "Hinweis", message: "Datensatz wurde gespeichert!")

    vornameTextField.text = ""
    nameTextField.text = ""
    straßeTextField.text = ""
    ortTextField.text = ""
    plzTextField.text = ""
}

func loadData() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Kontakte>(entityName: "Kontakte")

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "nameTextField contains %@", nameTextField.text!)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    var fetchResults: [Kontakte] = []
    do {
        try fetchResults  = managedObjectContext!.fetch(fetchRequest)
            if(fetchResults.count > 0) {
                nameTextField.text = fetchResults[0].name
                vornameTextField.text = fetchResults[0].vorname
                straßeTextField.text = fetchResults[0].strasse
                ortTextField.text = fetchResults[0].ort
                plzTextField.text = fetchResults[0].plz
            }else {
                showAlertViewWithTitle(title: "Hinweis", message: "Datensatz nicht gefunden!")
            }
        }catch {
            showAlertViewWithTitle(title: "Fehler", message: "Bei der Verarbeitung ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!")
        }
}

func showAlertViewWithTitle(title: String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Schliessen", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

[image after saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjjDv.png)

The error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (nameTextField CONTAINS "Lebowski")'
```

I am grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

I do normally something like this

```
    var contacts = [Kontakte]()
```

And for example in viewDidLoad

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let contactFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Kontakte")

    do {
        contacts = try managedContext.fetch(contactFetch) as! [Kontakte]
        // loop results
        for contact in contacts {
           print(contact.vorname)
        }

    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch contacts: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: I can see how you fetch the objects from the container and fil your array with them. 
But is there a way to modify my code to solve the problem? 

As far as I can tell my function loadData() is not able to find a contact with the searched name in my array, because there wa no object to get fetched.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am not the person to let things unfinished so I kept on looking for my mistake. I made a mistake with the predicate function, where i compared the content of my textfield with the attribute "nameTextField" which is no attribute of my entity.

Comment: Ok, gut das du den Fehler dann gefunden hast, aber du musst zugeben, dass wir den Fehler nie gefunden hätten ;)